# Calling web services from Mainframe batch programs

Tags: java, .net, web-services, batch-file, mainframe

We are currently looking at doing a partial migration away from a Main Frame.

Some of the functionality written in Mainframe Cobol is called from Mainframe Batch programs.

We would like to move these cobol programs off the mainframe.

If for example we moved the functionality in the cobol programme to a Java or .Net web service. Is the a way to call this web service from a Mainframe batch programme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I am not sure if there is a way to call web services directly from Cobol, but we had a similar problem trying to call web services from the iSeries(AS400) using RPG and CL.

In the end, we wrote a simple Socket program in java, running on a server, which we called an WebServiceBridge, and the bridge program simply took the data from the socket program and constructed a webservice call in Java. The results of which we simply piped back through the socket.

If Cobol struggles with web services, then this may be a simple solution. Be aware however that your bridge will need to be monitored, resilient and always available in the same way as you would design your web services.

Comment: There are a number of options for Cobol batch to access web services.  The OP could wire up their own soap using the built-in xml parser and generator; they could route to TS/SOAP using the EXEI interface; the could leverage RD/z support for invoking web services; there are a number of 3rd party products that will allow such access.

Comment: There is also an MQ Integrator bridge product from IBM that will do this as well.  Sorry I forgot to mention it in previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

In a previous life, I wrote assembler routines to call the TCP/IP stack from PL/1 using techniques described here which would work for COBOL as well:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r9.halz002/tcpipapis.htm

Sadly I can't share them with you but they weren't too complex.
Bear in mind that the web service is going to be interested in ASCII or UTF-8 and your COBOL is probably running EBCDIC so someone has to do the translation.

Once you can talk to a socket, you will have to formulate your web request with various headers and then decode the results... it's not trivial but it is possible.
'hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[this presumes that by "web service" you mean HTTP(S) and SOAP]

The API for CICS TS 3.1 and above includes the ability for application programs to invoke web services.  CICS applications are normally interactive, but can be invoked from existing batch applications via the external CICS interface.  This interface uses CICS commareas, so the data being passed must fit into a 32K buffer.

Another route into CICS is MQSeries (now rebranded WebSphereMQ).  In this case, your batch application would put the data (no 32K limit in this case) into a queue which is defined as triggered, the trigger monitor would start the CICS application automatically.  The CICS application would return the response to the web service via the response queue.

If you did either of these, I would expect the clock time on the batch job to increase.  It simply takes longer to travel across the network to execute some code than it does to execute that code locally.

Comment: +1 Thanks but in this case we just have batch, no CICS, but we could still go via MQ.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it. Using a c language program to make the http calls and a cobol interface program with cobol copybook so it looks to an app like any other program call. All http headers are converted to ascii and back by the c program and payload is converted off host.